Use nameConstraints to exclude all names but a few in OpenSSL
I want to use the x.509v3 certificate name constraint extension to exclude all names, except for one or a few of them, using OpenSSL's openssl.cnf file.
The directive is
nameConstraints  = critical, permitted;DNS:.example.com, correct me if I am wrong.
This should allow domain "example.com" and its subdomains, if I am not mistaken.\
I considered the following: in sshd, if you specify only the allowed name --or IP address--, sshd will understand that you want to exclusively allow THAT one name --or IP address--. What's the equivalent in openssl.cnf?

Name constraints extension is the right way, as long as client understands this extension. Not all crypto libraries implement support for name constraints. For example, it seems that Apple products still don't support it. Given that extension must be marked as critical (per RFC 5280), such applications/products will reject certificates with unsupported critical extension.
Speaking about configuration, your understanding is close to what you need, though:

The directive is nameConstraints  = critical, permitted;DNS:.example.com
<...>
This should allow domain "example.com" and its subdomains

only subdomains, because "example.com" don't satisfy ".example.com" pattern. Leading dot allows only subdomains, not parent domain. So you need to add parent domain in addition to subdomains pattern. You can restrict it even to individual host names if necessary, though it is a bit very rare scenario.
Note that Name Constraints extension is defined in CA certificates and apply to subordinate certificates, not to own certificate where extension is defined.

Understood! Then I may not use it, if it may cause problems. And thank you for correcting my mistake.
I still wish to learn the specific way to exclusively allow one [sub]domain name. Is it by allowing one, and that'll be interpreted as the only one allowed?

If you specify only one domain, then only one domain will be permitted. Note that ".example.com" will permit entire domain subtree, such as "sub.example.com", "sub.sub.example.com" and so on. But "example.com" (without leading dot) will permit only this particular domain and no hosts in this domain.

understood! thank you very much, mr Podans.
